# Tesseract does not read zeros in specific cases

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

i am writing a small software, that reads the terminal output of another device via webcam (no, screenshare etc. is not possible).

This is the first time I use tesseract, so I shurely made a few rookie mistakes.

I have been trying to read the text and got quite good results, but now I noticed, that it always misses zeros in two specific cases (See image) the wired thing is, when it misses those zeros, it assigns the width of the leading character + width of the zero  to the leading char. Or to say it more clearly: When I draw a box around the leading char, it draws the box around the leading char + the zero, but only reads the leading char.

I tried:

- Rescaling
- different PSM settings
- different OEM Settings
- Zooming in on the specific area
- Setting filter threasholds and converting the image to greyscale. The only time this brought significantly better result (with the zero) was when I had set the filter so agressively that all the red text disappeared.

The size of capital letters is at ~30pixels, which should be perfect (according to https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/c/Wdh_JJwnw94/m/24JHDYQbBQAJ )

Here is the codeblock, responsible  for the OCR:

```
    configString = r'--oem 3 psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ():.$£B '
    boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img, config=configString)
    print(boxes)
```

The overall imagesize is 1280 x 720

In the  third image, you can see a part of the "print(boxes)" result showing (or not showing) the missing Zero. I marked the Y-coordinates of the leading char.In Comarison to the Y-Coordinates of the other chars, you can see  the marked one is much wider(since it has the width of the missing zero added to its own width). On the second Image, you can see how the boxes get drawn all the way to the missing zeros. The Zero in the green circle gets recognized ~10% of the time, the zero in the blue circle  is never recognized.

All the  other zeros never have any problems

Thanks for your help!

It even does the same, if I blank out all the surrounding Text, as seen in Image 4.

[This is the webcam feed before OCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKS1B.png)
[Image after OCR, with boxes drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNeyq.png)
[pard of "print(boxes)" that shows the anomally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Vjz.png)
[Text around line with missing Zero is blanked out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poh6O.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Tesseract documentation and focus on preprocessing. I just did quick tests and here is the result:

```
>tesseract TKS1B_inv_gs_dpi_border_bw2.png -
Detected current bit errors: no
Detected current overflows: no
Detected current link changes: @

Overall results:

Transmitted frames: 0 (tx events disabled)
Received frames: 286001

ERROR: Lost events: 5228

ERRCR: 2614 on port DNetl.Dirl.MP1

ERROR: 2614 on port Vietl.Dirl.Mp1
Detected bit errors: no

Detected overflows: no

ERROR: Detected link changes: 10

ERROR: 4 on port DHetl.Dirl.MP1
```

[image]

The problem is with red text - not sure if this is interesting for you. If yes, then convert the red color to white in the first place.

The next problem is that 0 is not correctly recognized - but it is there, but you filtered the result with `tessedit_char_whitelist`... Maybe more aggressive blurring could help, or get rid of tessedit_char_whitelist and use replace('@', '0')

The problem of 1/l in a context like "DNet1" or "Dir1" will be hard. Maybe try other techniques like sharpening to make it more distinguishable...

Comment: I tried denoising (is that what you meant with "more aggressive blurring"? with cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored() that did help a bit, but lengthend my cycletime by around 1 second. Getting rid of the whitelist also worked, but also lengthended my cycletime a lot. But that brought me the idea to include "@" to the whitelist and weplace it with a zero afterwards as you wrote. Its a bit of a workaround, but it works!

Comment: Bluring e.g. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Comment: Replace a character after ocr is dangerous and not recommended. Have you the chance to improve the source image? Also the last line is damaged.

Comment: Validation of results (e.g. spellchecking, not finding an expected pattern, or finding unexpected letters as @) and postprocessing of OCR results is common (must?). Yes, automatic correction could bring extra problems, but not dangerous.